# Access package contents from string argument in Modelica

Tags: modelica, dymola

I have a string vector with the names of some substances `vec = {"H2","O2"}`, and I would like to use these strings to access a `record` in a package such that

```
Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.SingleGasesData.'vec[1]'
```

returns the data of `H2`.

Is this possible in Modelica, or do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it manually:

```
import d = Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.SingleGasesData;
constant Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.DataRecord data[Species]={d.H2,d.O2};
```

It might be slow and requires some index tracking, but for small sizes it is doable.